# Uninstall [failed-installation]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Looking at [failed-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation) and its <s>318</s> 813 questions, I think the tag should be burninated.

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

  There seem to be two distinct types of questions:

  - The installation program failed with an error.
  - The installation program succeeded, but the installed program is not available, for example, because of forgetting to start the service.
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

  It doesn't feel on-topic to me; just the application tag would suffice.
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

  I don't think so.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

  As mentioned in point 1, no. A build from source failing due to missing a library is very different from forgetting to start a service after installation, and the skill sets needed to fix these problems are very different.

Furthermore, a lot of the questions have pretty useless titles like "Foobar failed to install", which don't help anyone, and there are even downright terrible ones like [Kinect SDK failing, but the error reported as a screenshot of a Chinese-language error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620850/install-kinect-sdk1-8-failed).

Comment: _Cleaning up after a [failed-installation]_

Comment: For what it's worth I'll often Google something like "Foobar won't install" or "Barfoo crashes when running" or "Bafbil won't do X" when something isn't working but I'm not getting enough or any feedback from the app on *why*. With hopes that someone else might have used that phrase somewhere with more descriptions that I might search on to narrow down the problem so I can find a solution.

Comment: By the way, the tag is hardly on-topic to begin with. Something failing to install rarely involves programming, unless it's because an installer you wrote is failing somehow. Many of these belong on Super User, Server Fault, Unix.SE, etc., and based on the first page of questions with those tags, I've only found about 1 that is on-topic. +1 for burninating to me.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say [failed-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation) is worth uninstalling. ;-)

This tag is hardly even on-topic: most of the questions [on the first page of ones tagged with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation) are only on topic because of the thing it involves, where the other tags are wholly sufficient. A few of them really belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com), etc., because they have nothing to do with programming. I'm not going to post every one of them here, but here's a few examples:

- [ClickOnce - System.InvalidCastException While installing Windows IoT Core Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37513189/2693146)

  This is only on topic because it deals with a developer tool not installing. IMHO [failed-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation) is a distraction more than anything helpful.
- [Kali Linux installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37408144/2693146)

  This might belong on Super User or maybe Unix.SE, but it would be a low quality question on either of those two. I've already flagged it as off-topic.
- [iOS app installed failed thru iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37264793/2693146)

  This is on topic because the developer was having issues getting his own app to install on production (end users') devices.
- [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1113088/2693146)

  This 6-year-old question dealt with a missing shared library on Android, and [failed-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation) is more misleading than helpful in this case.
- [I am not able to install packages for SharePoint 2013 February 2016 CU on my Windows Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861998/2693146)

  This question belongs on Server Fault, and I've flagged it accordingly.
- [MOXA Nport 5110A Driver Failed Installation (On Linux Ubuntu 14.04)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32323756/2693146)

  This belongs on Super User or Unix.SE, and I've flagged it accordingly (for specifically Super User, but it's too old to migrate at this point).

Most of the other questions are about Azure, VS, Python, other various IDEs and/or runtimes, etc. failing to install, but the existing tags are fully sufficient for 90% of them, and this one adds nothing at best. The few that seem like they need this really need retagged with, for example, [android-manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-manifest) for the half-dozen or so questions over that awkwardly generic error with invalid Android app manifests.

Oh, and you're right that most of these are low quality to begin with.

So, I'm all for burnination.