# Uninstall [installation]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

This tag is even more vague than its friend [failed-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation) that was <strike>uninstalled</strike> removed back in [2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316939/735926). I don’t feel that it brings much information to a question, and I’m not sure why would anyone want to follow it.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**
   Kind of, yes: these questions are indeed about installing something.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   Yes and no: a question about a specific issue when installing `gcc` is on-topic but something about installing your dishwasher is not.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Kind of: [mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb)+[installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) makes it clear that the question is about installing MariaDB. But then, any very broad tag like [print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/print) or [writing-a-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing-a-program) would be acceptable.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   Not really: installing any piece of software can be vastly different from another. Knowing how to install Python modules on Linux doesn’t give you any expertise about installing [Atmel Studio 7.0 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57606081/735926).

Comment: I can imagine two large groups of using this tag: 1. Installing a **well-known software**, used for programming. 2. **Writting a software**, which should be installable. I am expert of [tag:cmake] tag, which is about writting a projects. Installation is important part of such projects, and CMake developers provide many functions and technologies for that purpose. So [tag:cmake] + [tag:installation] has a lot of sense for me. And even a software may be developed by different technologies, its installation has many common aspects. So being **expert** in such "installation" is actually possible.

Comment: "kind of, yes", "yes and  no", "kind of" and "not really" are not exactly hard NO's. Your own choice of phrasing essentially already tips you off how this burnination request is going to go. I would fail to see the value in such a tag either to be honest, but we shouldn't be too creative with the rules.

Answer (score 6):

This is a stretch:

> - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
>
>   Yes and no: a question about a specific issue when installing gcc is on-topic but something about installing your dishwasher is not.

Installing a dishwasher would never be on-topic for a programming website, no matter what tags you selected.  Installing GCC would be on-topic, as would installing IDEs (and related plugins).

This is a red herring:

> - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
>
>   Not really: installing any piece of software can be vastly different from another. Knowing how to install Python modules on Linux doesn’t give you any expertise about installing Atmel Studio 7.0 on Windows.

Installing software used to program is still suitably on-topic for the site, and it would be nonsensical to expect that someone who knows Python and has only ever worked with Python to know how to install something like that.  It's kinda like someone asking a question in Delphi and all you have are Kotlin developers online at the time - no reason to then declare Delphi as unsuitable for the site just because no one's around to answer that question.

Comment: I didn’t really explain myself really well: what I meant is you cannot have an expertise on this tag. Someone with a gold badge on [tag:python] can very likely answer almost any new question about Python. That’s not true for someone with a gold badge on [tag:installation] because it’s too vague.