# Cleaning up after a [failed-installation]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We have [failed-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation), this was [previously discussed in 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316939/1509264) and had 318 questions, it now has 813.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It is a meta-tag. Something failed to install but what failed to install and why vary question-by-question and you need additional context of the software that failed and the surrounding environment to be able to answer the question.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It is a general/broad concept that is relevant to all users installing and configuring software and is not something specific to programming. The topic [installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) is probably not on-topic for StackOverflow, let alone [failed-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed-installation).

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, it can't stand on its own.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

You need the context of the software being installed and the environment it is being installed into be able to answer the question. About the best you can say about the tag is that it is a sign-post that the question is off-topic for StackOverflow.